# 2's complement of a Decimal number, without converting it to binary form?

Tags: c++, binary, bit-manipulation, bit

How can I convert e.g. n=52 (110100) into a decimal number which represents its 2's complement (i.e., 12 (001100))?
Is there a formula/trick using bit manipulation (using C++)?

Comment: How much have you read about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)? Any decent resource about it should have told you how to convert numbers one way or the other (and if you know one way it's possible to deduce the other).

Comment: Besides, converting doesn't make much sense unless you're dealing with negative integers. If you really had a six-bit integer, then `110100` should have been a negative number.

Comment: `~n + 1` will give you 2's complement of `n`. This is how integers are converted into their 2's complement form. But you should read more about "Why 2's complement form is used?".

Answer (score 2):

If **x-bit** number then, `2^x - n` will give you the 2's complement of **n** in decimal.

In your case, you considered 6-bit numbers, so `64 - 52` = `12` is the 2's complement of `52`.

Also note that `52` should be interpreted as `-12` in signed 6-bit notation represented in 2's complement.